# Multiply row with above row and obtain an average

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel table with lets say 500 columns and 2 rows. I want to multiply each cell in the second row with the cell above, in the first row. Then get the average of the sum.

Example:

```
3 4 1 2 5
1 3 3 5 1
```

Solution would be: (3*1 + 4*3 + 1*3 + 2*5 + 5*1) / number of columns

What would the command look like in Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For data in rows 1 and 2 use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1:1,2:2)/COUNT(1:1)
```

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I was looking for!
It's a ; not a , between those two arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd do:

1) In the third row first column enter "=A1+A2".  Copy/paste that across the entire row to propagate.

2) In another column somewhere enter "AVERAGE(C1:C500)".

That cell in #2 should give you the answer.

Comment: Yes, that would be a solution, but I want to avoid having an extra row, just for buffer.